# In rails, how do I use REST with the link_to helper for the CRUD?

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-3.2

the CRUD being:

- index
- create
- new
- edit
- show
- update
- destroy
- delete

Answer (score 1):

on the config/routes.rb file, add the following:

```
resources: comments  # its aplural version of an existing model
```

and rails will make available some methods to link to methods in your controller, you can find these methods by typing in the terminal:

```
rake routes
```

with the output of that use the first column and add "_path" or "_url"

those can be used in a rails "link_to" method, example:

```
link_to "this is the text for the link", new_comment_path
```